# How to Fix Horizontal Text Overflow in React Table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, overflow, word-wrap

I have a table in React that works well in a defaulted desktop view; however, when down scaled to a phone, this table significantly overflows with text.

All of my efforts to fix this thus far have been changing the table's style component, changing the max-width, whiteSpace, and overflow properties for example.  These have not worked however, and I am searching for someone who might have any ideas of what I could pursue to fix this.

Here is a picture of the problem:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your table is simple (no ordering, grouping, searching, etc) as an alternative solution instead of table you may reach same display by using divs positioned flex. In mobile view then u may use power of responsivity

Comment: Hi Osman thanks for the idea.  Unfortunately the table is not so simple and requires a lookup.

Answer (score 0):

if you still wanna do that ellipse thing, here is the solution.

Given a fixed width for table (i.e; width 100% for table and table-layout as fixed)

```
 .text-ellipse{
    display: -webkit-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 1; /* how many lines you wanna restrict */
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
 }
```

Comment: Hi Madan!  I applied your CSS on the Table component but am still having problems.  Should this be applied elsewhere?